# Handle multiple imgeview with single onclick (View view) method

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, inflector

I create multiple imageviews programatically by inflating one layout and set id to that imageview. all these task i perform in for loop. i want to set on click listener on these programatically created imageviews. i set onclick listener but its not working.

My code:-

**mainlinearlayout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout_breakfast"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorLightWhiteShade"
android:orientation="horizontal">
```

**layout2.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:weightSum="10"
android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_breakfast_food_name_layout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Food Name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/delete_button_layout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edit_button_layout2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_delete"/>

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/edit_button_layout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_edit"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
  LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_breakfast);
 for (int i = 0; i < breakfastArraylistSize; i++) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout2_breakfast, null);
        TextView textview_food_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_breakfast_food_name_layout2);
        Log.d("textview_food_name id", String.valueOf(1 + (i * 3)));
        textview_food_name.setId(1 + (i * 3));  textview_food_name.setText(foodBreakfastDiaryDetailsArrayList.get(i).get("foodName"));
        Log.d("foodName", foodBreakfastDiaryDetailsArrayList.get(i).get("foodName"));
        layout.addView(view);

        imageview_delete_breakfast = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button_layout2);
        imageview_delete_breakfast.setId(2 + (i * 3));
        imageview_delete_breakfast.setOnClickListener(this);
        Log.d("imageview_delete_breakfast id", String.valueOf(DiaryScreenActivity.this.imageview_delete_breakfast.getId()));

    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  
    String foodid_Breakfast = "";
        foodid_Breakfast = foodBreakfastDiaryDetailsArrayList.get(i).get("foodID");
        int imageViewDeletePos = getIndexOFValue(foodid_Breakfast, foodBreakfastDiaryDetailsArrayList);
        Log.d("imageViewDeletePos", String.valueOf(imageViewDeletePos));
        ImageView imageview_edit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_button_layout2);
        imageview_edit.setId(3 + (i * 3));
        imageview_edit.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

**Onclicklistener**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == DiaryScreenActivity.this.imageview_delete_breakfast.getId()) {

Log.d("imageview_delete_breakfast id", String.valueOf(DiaryScreenActivity.this.imageview_delete_breakfast.getId()));
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Delete food")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this food?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete

                        // delete food item
                        DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = DataBaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                        try {
                            dataBaseHelper.openDataBaseC("M");

                            for (int i = 0; i < foodBreakfastDiaryDetailsArrayList.size(); i++) {

                                String foodid_Breakfast = foodBreakfastDiaryDetailsArrayList.get(i).get("foodID");
                                Log.d("foodid_Breakfast", foodid_Breakfast);
                                int imageViewDeletePos = getIndexOFValue(foodid_Breakfast, foodBreakfastDiaryDetailsArrayList);
                                Log.d("imageViewDeletePos", String.valueOf(imageViewDeletePos));
                            }

                            dataBaseHelper.closeC("M");

                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();

  }
}
```

Comment: Is your Log (`Log.d("imageview_delete_breakfast id", String.valueOf(DiaryScreenActivity.this.imageview_delete_breakfast.getId()));`) displayed in the Logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add onClick inside loop. like :

```
imageview_delete_breakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do what you want for individual click
                }
            });
```